# Ambiguous functions when compiling in OS X Mavericks

Tags: c++, compilation, osx-mavericks, ambiguous

I've been fighting to install GDL on my Macbook, 10.9.2, and I came across a lot of problems when compiling.  Eventually I managed after lots of issues of the form:

```
/Downloads/gdl-0.9.4/src/basic_fun.cpp:6415:14: error: call to 'isalpha' is ambiguous
        if (!isalpha(*p) && !isdigit(*p) && *p != '+' && *p != '.' && *p != '-') 
             ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/ctype.h:218:1: note: candidate function
isalpha(int _c)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/cctype:60:38: note: 
      candidate function
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY int isalpha(int __c) {return __libcpp_isalpha(__c);}
```

They're easily fixed by changing `foo()` to `::foo()`, but it seems a bit hacky.  The problems continue even with Homebrew installed things like wxmac.  I had to alter one of the headers to make it work - same problem with ambiguous functions.  Interestingly the problem doesn't occur with `isdigit()` - meaningful?

The problem seems to be conflict between Xcode's libc++ and the headers in /usr/include.  Is there a simple way around this?

This was not an issue when I compiled GDL on my girlfriend's Mountain Lion machine.

Comment: Minimal testcase? I can't reproduce using the XCode Tools command line.

Comment: Slightly hard to give a test case as it comes from:

cmake .. -DREADLINEDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/ -DHDF=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_PREFIX=/usr/local/gd

Make then fails when compiling a number of files, the first one to fail is usually basic_fun.cpp.  The rest of the compile errors are identical, but with tolower(), toupper(), isalpha(), isspace().  The errors in wxmac are wchar fuctions.  There is also " gdl-0.9.4/src/gsl_fun.cpp:3892:9: error: no viable overloaded '*='" which I fixed with an explicit cast.  I'll try to knock up a sample cpp file that errors in this way.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be certain, but this sounds very like a problem I've been chasing, in this case with tolower(). I suspect somewhere you are including a header that defines macros for the various character handling routines like isalpha(), tolower() etc. In my case this was the Python include file pyport.h, which was included by some Boost code. What happens next is quite complicated but any of the following work to fix it:

- Remove any 'using namespace std' statements.
- Use ::tolower() etc.
- Using std::tolower() etc., works but doesn't feel right.
- Re-order include statements so cctype is included before anything
  like pyport.h that defines tolower() etc as macros.
- Simply put a #include cctype as early in your code as possible.

What follows is taken from a rather long-winded report I wrote describing the problem I hit. Even if it isn't exactly your problem, it sounds as if it's definitely related.

Essentially, the following example program does not compile, at least on my Yosemite system, which has Boost installed and is running Python 2.7. Other OS X machines with different Python versions may be OK.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

int main() { 
    return 0;
}
```

You get two errors complaining about 'tolower' being ambiguous. Both errors are essentially the same and look like this:

```
In file included from demo1.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl.hpp:23:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/rfc2818_verification.hpp:99:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ssl/impl/rfc2818_verification.ipp:146:14: error: 
      call to 'tolower' is ambiguous
    else if (tolower(*p) == tolower(*h))

/usr/include/ctype.h:292:1: note: candidate function
tolower(int _c)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cctype:149:38: note: 
      candidate function
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY int tolower(int __c) {return __libcpp_t...
```

The reasons are quite complicated, but the underlying problem comes from how the Python include file pyport.h messes with the various character handling routines like tolower(). Basically, it redefines tolower() as a macro to get around issues to do with character width. This macro then confuses the way the standard cctype include file also tries to handle tolower(). The result is a tolower() in the global namespace and another in the std namespace. The problem finally shows up if tolower() is used in a scope where 'using namespace std' applies.

Here's that previous example reduced to some minimal code that triggers the problem. The pyport.h file includes ctype.h and wctype.h and then has a #define for tolower(). The code following that is the sort of thing that then causes the problem, namely including wchar.h and cctype and then having a 'using namespace std' and a reference to tolower() (which is what the Boost, rfc2818_verification.ipp does, but any code that does the same will trigger the problem).

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#define tolower(c) towlower(btowc(c))

#include <wchar.h>
#include <cctype>
char GetLower (const char c) {
   using namespace::std;
   return tolower(c);
}

int main() { 
   return 0;
}
```

OK, what's going on here? The problem is basically that pyport.h defines tolower() as a macro, combined with way the cctype include file handles tolower() when tolower() is defined as a macro.

pyport.h is trying to deal with problems Python has with recent versions of tolower() etc that work on wide characters, because this breaks some things. It deals with this by defining tolower() as a macro that explicitly works on narrow characters. And this works most of the time.

cctype is trying to deal with what happens on systems where the ordinary tolower() routine is simply defined as a macro, as opposed to an actual routine. In that case it defines a routine in std:: that does what tolower() does (using the macro to do so) and has this replace that macro. What it does is basically:

```
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD

#ifdef tolower
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY int __libcpp_tolower(int __c) {return tolower(__c);}
#undef tolower
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY int tolower(int __c) {return __libcpp_tolower(__c);}
#else  // tolower
using ::tolower;
#endif  // tolower

_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
```

On machines where tolower is just a routine in the normal global namespace, it simply issues a 'using ::tolower'. This is the normal case on OS X.

The way this all combines to cause problems is that in this case, at the point when cctype is included, tolower() has been defined as a macro, but for the private purposes of Python, and NOT because that's the normal way of defining it. The result is that there is a tolower() in global namespace (defined by ctype.h in the normal way) AND a tolower() in std:: namespace (defined by cctype, which has been deceived by the macro definition declared by pyport.h.)

And that isn't a problem if you use use tolower() with no explicit namespace, because it picks up the normal global tolower(). It's OK if you use std::tolower(), or ::tolower() explicitly, because you get what you've asked for. It's only a problem if you have a 'using namespace std' and then just use tolower(), because you've told the compiler it can look in std for a tolower, and it will do so and find one. But it will also find the normal global tolower(). And then it doesn't know what to do and there's your error.

Ways to fix it?

It depends on whether the problem shows up in code you can change or code you can't (or shouldn't) like the Boost include files. If you can change the code:

o Don't use 'using namespace std;' - it's not a great idea anyway.

o Use ::tolower(). Then there's no ambiguity.

o Use std::tolower(), although that only works when cctype defines it; normally it doesn't.

If you can't change the code file that triggers the problem:

o Re-order the include files so whatever includes cctype comes before the one that includes pyport.h. Then cctype doesn't see the definition of tolower() as a macro and all's well.

o Put #include cctype as early in your code as possible. Then it gets dealt with before pyport.h confuses things, and any later include of it will be ignored. That may be the simplest fix of all.